# issue when launching html file in chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome

when I was launching a html file in chrome browser  and if we are trying to append a keyword and GUID with the url, `'#'` and is replaced by `'%23'`. But it is working properly with internet explorer. why?

```
string arg = "index.html" + "#" + guid;
processBrowser.StartInfo.Arguments = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), arg);
```

Comment: add the code please!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `decodeURIComponent` method and pass the arg.

```
processBrowser.StartInfo.Arguments = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), decodeURIComponent(arg));
```

Comment: that i have tried ..but when launching html file still # is replaced by %23